# Varnish isnt caching with pagespeed

Tags: nginx, varnish

I'm using nginx pagespeed + varnish but varnish isnt cache. The wordpress works well..but varnish (4.0) i'm not getting response via curl

*curl -I http://example.com*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Link: <http://www.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Date: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 17:04:57 GMT
X-Page-Speed: 1.11.33.4-0
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Age: 196
X-Cache: cached
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

*cat /etc/default/varnish*

```
....
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

*cat /etc/varnish/default.vcl*

```
...
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8081";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}


$ ps aux -P | grep varnish
varnish  24427  0.0  0.6 125044  6920 ?        Ss   17:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd
varnish  24461  0.0  0.7 125044  7776 ?        Ss   17:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnish -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
vcache   24473  0.0  9.2 272024 93352 ?        Sl   17:04   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnish -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Users varnish and vcache are users in group with privileges (sudo).

$ cat /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
...
  server {
       listen       127.0.0.1:8081;
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

For Varnish and ngx_pagespeed to work well together, you'll have to configure rather sophisticated [Downstream Caching](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/downstream-caching)